# How to use GLUT in DEV C++?

Tags: opengl, glut

The compiler throws errors like:

```
"   [Linker error] main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x972): undefined reference to `_imp__glutReshapeFunc@4' "
```

Do you know how to use GLUT in Dev C++?

Comment: I thought DevC++ was dead, but it seems to have been [reborn](http://orwellengine.blogspot.com/)... Are you using the latest version? The prior ones are said to be leaky and buggy. As for me, I'd rather use [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: It looks Code::Blocks is dead now. The last update was almost 2 years ago.

Comment: Wow, been in Visual Studio land for too long...

Comment: My, God! Windows development has hope!

Answer (score 2):

DevC++ is seriously outdated. I recommend using Codeblocks instead.

The error line you quoted simply indicated, that the linker is missing the functions of the GLUT library. Including the headers is not enough (they just provide the compiler with sort of an index). But the linker still needs to be told which libraries to actually link against.